# Multi-friend selector - non-functional when selecting 25-50 friends

Tags: facebook, apprequests

When attempting to send to a large number (about 25+) of requests to friends using the gallery view, multi friend selector that the request flow fails to display.

It appears as though the request is timing out; with the only evidence being this error:
"apprequests POST https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests 500" and the related Facebook pop-up and generic error message:

"Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can."

To reproduce:

- Start your facebook app
- Bring up the multi friend selector
- Select the maximum number of friends (50)
- Select 'Send Requests' button

At this point, another dialog should appear, asking to confirm to send the request to those 50 people.  However, that pop up never appears, and the recipients never get the request.